# How to create a formatting tool bar for NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I was looking at the [TextEditor](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TextEdit/Introduction/Intro.html) code provided by apple. However, I could not figure out how they managed to add that formatting toolbar on the top.

[image]

I know how to add a ruler view. But how to do add this foramatting view ?

Answer (score 4):

Eventually figured it out. All I had to do was.

textView.usesInspectorBar = true